Unwanted White Space Appears While Scrolling in Safari for React App
I'm encountering an issue where there is unwanted white space while scrolling on Safari, both on mobile and desktop versions. The problem does not appear in Chrome or Edge, where the page works as expected. The issue seems to be specific to Safari, causing a large gap or blank area, as shown in the attached image.
Environment Details:

Browsers Affected: Safari (Mobile & Desktop)

Browsers Working Fine: Chrome, Edge

Issue Occurs On:

Safari Mobile (iPhone)

Safari on macOS




enter image description here
Expected Behavior:
The page should scroll smoothly without any white space, as it does in Chrome and Edge.
Actual Behavior:
While scrolling in Safari, a large white gap appears, which disrupts the user experience.
<div className="inextlabs-webchat-body">
        <div className="inextlabs-webchat-messages" ref={messagesContainerRef}>
          {messages.map(
            (message, index) => (
              (
                <div
                  key={index}
                  className={`inextlabs-webchat-message ${message.from}`}
                  ref={index === messages.length - 1 ? lastMessageRef : null}
                >
                  {message.from === "bot" ? (
                    <>
                      <div className="animate__animated animate__slideInUp animate__faster">
                        {!message?.botMessage?.suggestedActions ? (
                          <>
                           
                          </>
                        ) : (
                          <>
                            {message?.heroCard?.text && (
                              <>
                              
                              </>
                          </> 
                             )     
                    </>
                  ) : (
                    <div className="inextlabs-webchat-user-message-container">
                      {message?.userMessage.attachmentURL && (
                        <div className="inextlabs-webchat-user-message-attachment">
                          <img
                            src={message.userMessage.attachmentURL}
                            alt="User"
                            width={"100%"}
                          />
                        </div>
                      )}
                      <p className="inextlabs-webchat-user-message m-0">
                        {message.userMessage.text}
                      </p>
                      <div className="flex gap-1">
                        <span className="inextlabs-webchat-user-message-timestamp">
                          {message.timestamp}
                        </span>
                        <div className="inextlabs-webchat-user-message-status">
                          <RiCheckDoubleLine color="#478d47" />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              )
            )

css:
.inextlabs-webchat-messages {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inextlabs-webchat-message {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: start;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.15px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-size: 15px;
  & p {
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  & img {
    border-radius: 15px;
  }
  ol li {
    margin: 10px 0;
    line-height: 2rem !important;
  }
  ul li {
    margin: 10px 0;
    line-height: 2rem !important;
  }
}

.inextlabs-webchat-body {
  height: 75%;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: $body-bg;
}

